# Adding new line after every Nth occurrence of delimiter

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file `roll.txt` with below data in comma delimited format without any newline.

```
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789','432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456','22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```

I need to insert a New Line after every 6<sup>th</sup> occurrence of the comma delimiter along with no comma at the end of each line.

Below is the expected output:

```
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789'
'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456'
'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```

I am using below `sed` command which is not working.

```
sed 's/[^,]//g'
```

Answer (score 5):

At least with GNU `sed` and **assuming your fields cannot contain embedded comma separators**, you could do

```
sed 's/,/\n/6; P; D' roll.txt
```

which repeatedly attempts to replace the 6th comma with a newline, print, and then delete the portion of pattern space up to the newline.

NOTE: it is not necessary to implement an explicit labelled test/branch, since the `D` command implicitly "restarts the cycle" on the remainder of the line:

> D
>  If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle
>   as if the d command was issued. Otherwise, delete text in the pattern
>   space up to the first newline, *and restart cycle with the resultant
>   pattern space, without reading a new line of input*.

(credit to @RakeshSharma for clarifying this).

Ex.

```
sed 's/,/\n/6; P; D' roll.txt 
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789'
'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456'
'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```

---

Alternatively, with Perl's `Text::CSV` module:

```
perl -MText::CSV -ne '
  BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new()} 
  @fields = $p->fields() if $p->parse($_); 
  do {
    print join ",", splice @fields, 0, 6; print "\n";
  } while @fields
' roll.txt
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789'
'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456'
'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```

Comment: The "test" **t** command in sed is not really needed. **sed 's/,/\n/6;P;D'** will suffice. The "D" command when operating on a pattern space without newline(s) behaves just like its lowercase counterpart.

Comment: If you replace the `\n` with a backslash followed by an actual newline, this would even be POSIX compliant, so the answer is not limited to GNU `sed` anymore.

Answer (score 5):

With `tr`&`paste`:

```
tr ',' '\n' <infile |paste -sd',,,,,\n'
```

for more readability and understandable:

```
tr ',' '\n' <infile |paste --serial --delimiters=',,,,,\n'
```

In such a case when you wanted to add a NewLine at every say, ***N=100*** position, then you may not prefer to input 99 commas `',,,,,,,,,, ... ,\n'`; instead let `printf` generate it for you with brace-expansion.

```
tr ',' '\n' <infile |paste -sd $(printf '%.1s' ,{1..99})'\n'
```

from [**`man paste`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html):

```
-d, --delimiters=LIST
       reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs

-s, --serial
       paste one file at a time instead of in parallel
```

Comment: `paste -d, - - - - - -` and `pr -6ats,` would work too

Comment: @Sundeep your `tr ...| pr -6ats,` does but not `tr ...| paste -d, - - - - - -`, also I suggest you post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: good point about trailing commas, forgot about that.. anyway, didn't add an answer as I feel the question is duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

A variation on [αғsнιη's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446401/116858):

```
$ tr ',' '\n' <file | paste -d, - - - - - -
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789'
'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456'
'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```

This assumes that none of the fields have embedded commas in them.

If the input does not have a multiple of six fields, you may get output like

```
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789'
'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456'
'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
hello,world,,,,
```

Comment: this won't give expected result untill a long line is not multiply of 6, add `,'something'` at the end of the line and see the result. you will have training commas (6- number of printed column in last line)

Comment: @αғsнιη Thanks, I've added a note about this.  It may actually be preferable this way since there will always be six comma-separated columns in the output no matter what.