# Add two delimiters after every sixth comma

Tags: text-processing, sed, text-formatting

I'm trying to [expand on this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446366/adding-new-line-after-every-nth-occurrence-of-delimiter) but can't figure out this issue:

Let's say I've got a file `roll.txt`:

```bash
echo "'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789','432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456','22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'" >> roll.txt
```

I can place a newline after every sixth comma with the following sed command:

```bash
sed 's/,/,\n/6; P; D' roll.txt
```

```
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789',
'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456',
'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```

However, when I try to place two newlines after every sixth comma:

```bash
sed 's/,/,\n\n/6; P; D' roll.txt
```

```
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789',

'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456',



'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```

I instead get two newlines after the sixth comma, and **four** newlines after the 12th comma. Why? And how can I get two newlines after every sixth comma?

Comment: The `P; D` sequence only prints and deletes up to the *first* `\n` - leaving the second `\n` at the beginning of the pattern space. If you have a recent version of GNU sed, try running it with the `--debug` option to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in steeldriver's comment, in each cycle you add two lines, but print and remove only one. This would grow worse for longer sequences, with 3 and 7 and 15 empty lines ...

Thus, don't do the replacement, if your first line is empty:

```
sed '/^\n/!s/,/,\n\n/6; P; D'
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for mult-char RS you could just define each record as being 6 non-commas-then-comma fields:

```
$ echo "'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789','432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456','22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'" |
awk -v RS='([^,]*,){0,6}' 'RT{print RT}'
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789',
'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456',
'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345',
```

and if you wanted to make sure every output line is 6 fields and only ends with `,` when the last field is empty so it's a valid CSV you could do:

```
$ echo "'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789','432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456','22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'" |
awk -v n=6 'BEGIN{RS="([^,]*,){0,"n"}"; FS=OFS=","} RT{$0=gensub(/,$/,"",1,RT); $n=$n; print}'
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789'
'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456'
'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345',
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

If you want to combine elements in Raku you can `batch` them together:

```
~$  raku -ne 'put join "\n", .split(",").batch(6).map: *.join(",");' roll.txt
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789'
'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456'
'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```

So to get two-newlines between each `batch`, just `join` on `\n\n`:

```
~$  raku -ne 'put join "\n\n", .split(",").batch(6).map: *.join(",");' roll.txt
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789'

'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456'

'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```

Raku's `batch` function is equivalent to Raku's `rotor(..., :partial)` call. If you want to drop incomplete sets of 6 elements at the end just call `rotor()`.

Finally, sometimes `split`ting doesn't always give you the answer you're looking for. In that case you can try `comb`ing through the data to extract elements of interest. The code below gives the exact equivalent to the answers above, but may be conceptually simpler. The only difficulty is that `'` apostrophe  can mess up one-liner quoting, so the character can be declared using its Unicode name `\c[APOSTROPHE]`:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put join "\n\n", .comb(/ \c[APOSTROPHE] \d+ \c[APOSTROPHE] /).batch(6).map: *.join(",");'  roll.txt
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789'

'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456'

'22234','3456','7890543','2345','567'
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611077/227738
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789','432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456','22234','3456','7890543','34567891','2345','567'" > roll.txt

cat roll.txt | sed -E "s/([^,]*,){6}/\0\n\n/g"
```

You can change the number of items repeated between commas by replacing it with the 6.

Comment: What is `\0`? Don't you simply mean `s/([^,]*,){6}/&\n\n/g`?

Comment: \0 in the replacement is the whole expression that is matched, same thing as &

Comment: It doesn't say so in the POSIX specification. The `\n` in the replacement is a GNU extension, so you are probably safe to use other GNU extensions as well, but I see no reason for using some cryptic non-standard code instead of the well-known standard.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s", $i FS ((i%6==0) ? ORS ORS: "") }END{print $NF; print ""}' file
'123456789','987651234','129873645','213456789','987612345','543216789',

'432156789','876543291','213465789','542637819','123456','23456',

'22234','3456','7890543','34567891,'2345','567'
```